# gtk3 file chooser and recent directory setup

Tags: linux, firefox, chromium, gtk3, file-chooser

after having changed my distro from an up-to-date Mint that contained

gtk3 3.24.18

to Arch that contains

gtk3 3.24.31
gtk4 4.4.1

I noticed a change in the file chooser dialogs, both in Firefox
as well as in Chromium.

The behaviour before was

> Go to a directory, and choose a file. Next time, the same directory will be
> opened again (and files in that directory will be shown)

The current behaviour is

> Go to a directory, and choose a file. Next time, either "Recent files"
> (startup-mode=recent) will be shown (which I don't want anyway), or
> "personal folder" will be shown (startup-mode=cwd). For me the personal
> folder is always $HOME, as the browsers are started from that directory.

As of the dconf-editor, the two variables

> /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/startup-mode
> /org/gtk/gtk4/settings/file-chooser/startup-mode

just have the values 'recent' or 'cwd'.

Question: Is there by any chance a way to get the old
behaviour back?

Thomas

PS

I know, there is a right-click menu option on the files that says "go to that file",
but that's not the intended behaviour (as it bears the risk of an accidental double click)

Also, the previously saved gtkfilechooser.ini (gtk-2.0)
did not work (when copied to settings.ini in the gtk-3.0
config folder).

Comment: gtk3 is bad precisely because issues like this have gone unresolved for over a year. And it's not just this, it's a flood of minor UI degradation.